# Roundcube Mailbox isn't a valid mbox file

Tags: php, nginx, debian, localhost, roundcube

When I login to my local Roundcube mail client from the web browser, it shows empty Inbox/Sent folders with an error message. I'm using php7.3, nginx, mysql as a local tech stack.

> Server error: STATUS: Mailbox isn't a valid mbox file (0.000 + 0.000
> secs).

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long investigation, I found the solution.

I just removed the leading line break from the file

```
/var/spool/mail/{YOUR_USERNAME}
```

And it worked like a charm.